# How to pick out "second" value using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The so-far expertly crafted script

```
iostat -p -x 1 2| grep $1[^[:digit:]] | awk '{print $9}'
```

will return two lines:

```
0.16
0.00
```

because iostat is taking two samples. But you already knew that. My question is since you and I both know it will be exactly two lines every time, how I pick out exactly the second?

Comment: What's with the reader flattery? Straightforward questions are generally easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `NR==2` before `{print $9}` to tell `awk` to match record 2.

For example, on my system,

```
$ iostat -x /dev/sda 1 2 | grep sda

$ iostat -x /dev/sda 1 2 | grep sda | awk 'NR==1 {print $9}'

$ iostat -x /dev/sda 1 2 | grep sda | awk 'NR==2 {print $9}'
```

produced

```
sda               0.11     1.04    2.00    1.28   125.95    63.24   115.15     0.07   21.04    4.66   46.60   2.36   0.78
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
0.07
0.00
```

where that "0.00" line is the result of the third command.

Additional note:  It isn't necessary to run a separate `grep` command, as `awk` can match text.  However, the awk script then needs an index variable.  The first of the following examples is a simple `grep` to show what `awk` works on.  The next two examples are straightforward `awk` code that has a match test to increment an index and another match test plus index test to print.  The last example shows how to get rid of extra appearances of the match expression.   Note, in these examples I replaced `print $9` with `print` for clarity, and `$1[^[:digit:]]` with `sda[^0-9]`.  Here are the examples which do the matching in `awk` instead of in `grep`:

```
$ iostat -p -x 1 2  | grep 'sda '
sda               0.11     1.04    2.00    1.28   125.70    63.16   115.09     0.07   21.04    4.66   46.57   2.36   0.78
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

$ iostat -p -x 1 2  | awk '/sda[^0-9]/ {++t} t==1 && /sda[^0-9]/ {print}'
sda               0.11     1.04    2.00    1.28   125.70    63.16   115.09     0.07   21.04    4.66   46.57   2.36   0.78

$ iostat -p -x 1 2  | awk '/sda[^0-9]/ {++t} t==2 && /sda[^0-9]/ {print}'
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

$ iostat -p -x 1 4  | awk '/sda[^0-9]/ && t++ && t==2 {print}'
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Comment: Works as intended on my system, but seems like it's printing everything on yours instead of one field?

Comment: In my answer, the first 2 lines of output are from `iostat -x /dev/sda 1 2 | grep sda`, ie, not followed by awk.  The other two lines of output show the results with NR==1 or NR==2 in place.  (Note, I edited answer to use sda instead of sdf, and in a minute will add a comment on that.)

Comment: @Mikhail, I added a note about how to do the grep from within awk.  For this application, it doesn't help much at all to match the lines in awk instead of in grep, but in other cases it will be more flexible or more general to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe it to `tail -1`, this will select the last line.

```
iostat -p -x 1 2| grep $1[^[:digit:]] | awk '{print $9}' | tail -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining `head` and `tail` lets you select any sequence of lines from the input:

```
(cmd) | tail -n+2 | head -n 1
```

gets the second line of input no matter how long the command's output is.